# Unable to activate feedzirra-0.1.3, because activesupport-3.2.3 conflicts with activesupport (~> 3.1.1) (Gem::LoadError)

Tags: ruby, rss, activesupport, feedzirra

I'm trying to use Feedzirra to parse an RSS feed, but I'm not able to have the activesupport gem required at the same time. It is telling me that I have a conflict between two version of activesupport. I have activesupport(3.2.3) and feedzirra (0.1.3).

This is the beginning of my code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'simple-rss'
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'
require 'rest-client'
require 'digest/sha1'
require 'mysql2'
require 'active_record'
```

And here is the error that I get when I run the file.

```
/Users/fil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1625:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate feedzirra-0.1.3, because activesupport-3.2.3 conflicts with activesupport (~> 3.1.1) (Gem::LoadError)
from /Users/fil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:740:in `activate'
from /Users/fil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:209:in `rescue in try_activate'
from /Users/fil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:206:in `try_activate'
from /Users/fil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:58:in `rescue in require'
from /Users/fil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
from wsj.rb:16:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas how to fix this? Would really love to use this gem.

Answer (score -1):

It appears that you have installed Rails (or ActiveSupport 3.2.3).  Feedzirra depends on 3.1:

https://github.com/pauldix/feedzirra/blob/master/feedzirra.gemspec#L29

If you're not already using Bundler, I'd suggest switching to use it ;)