# Unable to activate actionpack-3.2.9, because activesupport-3.2.11 conflicts with activesupport (= 3.2.9) (Gem::LoadError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, activesupport, actionpack

Unable to activate actionpack-3.2.9, because activesupport-3.2.11 conflicts with activesupport (= 3.2.9) (Gem::LoadError)

Anything to do with this?

[Unable to activate feedzirra-0.1.3, because activesupport-3.2.3 conflicts with activesupport (~> 3.1.1) (Gem::LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101554/unable-to-activate-feedzirra-0-1-3-because-activesupport-3-2-3-conflicts-with-a)

If so, I'm none the wiser.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you ever found an answer on this, but I found your question while I was trying to solve this myself. I ended up running:

```
gem install bundler
```

followed by:

```
bundle install
```

That updated the gems for my project and I don't get the error anymore.